# why is my disk volume method equation wrong? (integration)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

The volume of a solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by:

```
y=1/x^4, y = 0, x = 1, and x = 8
```

about the line y=-1 can be computed using the method of disks or washers via an integral...

The question is asking about the function and not the actual volume

I understand that it's a modification of the (pi)r^2dx idea and I got this:

```
pi(1+(1/x^4))^2
```

yet the place where I'm trying to submit this won't accept it. What am I doing wrong?

(Ignore the bounds I already have them listed as 1 to 8)

Comment: Hard to tell without having a complete question. Maybe you do not need to enter $\pi$? Usually function describes the radius, in this case $r(x)=1+\frac{1}{x^4}$.

Comment: it's just finding an equation that can be solved for the volume of the function rotated about y=-1, so there isn't any more of the question than what I posted already. I think pi is necessary though because pi is part of the form of pir^2 due to using the disk method to find volume